# Oracle Text catsearch left-truncated search

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

So according to [The oracle documentation on catsearch](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/csql.htm#GUID-40404FD8-528E-4121-93B8-20F4D9E0EB54__CHDJBGHE) it's not possible to use left-truncated searches with a catsearch text-query.
However, I've found that using double wildcards does have the desired effect of left-truncated queries.

E.g. `select * from foo where CATSEARCH(bar, '**zing', '')>0;` would find records with bar having the value of "this is amazing" while
`select * from foo where CATSEARCH(bar, '*zing', '')>0;` wouldn't

For the configuration of my word list, I have enabled **substring_index** and **prefix_index**. In the substring_index description, it does mention left-truncated (and double-truncated) wildcard usage.

I cannot find any reason as to why/how the double wildcard usage works, how optimized it is and whether or not it has any other side-effects.

So the ultimate questions:

- Why does this syntax work, is there anywhere that this is described?
- Is it equal, performance-wise?
- Are there any other side-effects people should be aware of when using this syntax?